# Can't find 'show in explorer' when I right click on res folder

Tags: android-studio, development-environment

I am trying to add files (images) to Android Studio. I used to do it by right click on res and then show in folder. But now I updated to Android Studio 3.1.4 and am not able find this option here. Is there also any other way to add files adding?

Comment: Did you try dragging files from explorer to res?

Comment: yes i did it is not  happenning

Comment: Just find it manually in the explorer

Answer (score 1):

Do you know where to find the project using a file manager (like Windows explorer)? If you don't, you can open Windows file manager (or one applying to your OS) and search for the title of your project to find it. From there you can locate your res folder, and paste the images there.

Comment: thanks a lot that helped .Needmore help i am a new student of android how can i get in touch with you

Answer (score 0):

You can also select the file you want to add, select *copy* and then right click the res folder and select *paste*.